# Can I pass a filtered CollectionViewSource to a method?

Tags: c#, wpf, observablecollection, generic-collections, icollectionview

I create a public CollectionView (cvs) and bind that to my ListView Control in a WPF application. Then there are a series of filters that add in delegates to filter my cvs object. Everything works fine in this aspect of the program.

```
public ICollectionView cvs { get; set; }
public ObservableCollection<T> TLIST
...
cvs = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(TLIST);
ListViewName.ItemsSource = cvs;
...
//Filters created 
cvs.Filter = groupFilter.Filter;
```

What I'm trying to do is create Excel files of the items in my list. I can send the entire collection (TLIST) to an OpenXML function and create my files just fine. Where I'm struggling is I want to only send the filtered items into the function and figure I need to somehow send the filtered cvs.

In short, what I'm trying to get is --> `cvs.ToList()` but this is not a valid operation. and getting the error

> "Unable to cast object of type
>   'System.Windows.Data.ListCollectionView' to type
>   'System.Collections.Generic.List`1"

Anything glaringly obvious that I'm doing wrong? Any guidance is appreciated.

Note: Even when I inspect cvs it shows all the items not just the filtered ones.

Comment: I understand I could probably just filter my TLIST with the same criteria but was hoping there was a smarter way to utilize my already filtered collection.

Comment: Looks like you are trying to store a ListCollectionView into a variable (or pass as a parameter) that is defined as List<something> and you didn't include that code.  If the next line was `var something=cvs.ToList();` I would expect that line to work just fine.

Comment: I am trying to convert cvs.ToList() via "var list = (List<T>)cvs.ToList();"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try the below which gives filtered list.

```
List<MyObject> lst = cvs.Cast<MyObject>().ToList();
```

Comment: and bingo was his-name-O

Comment: Yes, the CollectionView stuff doesn't support the newer IEnumerable<T>, but uses the older IEnumerable, which needs to be cast for most operations to work on it.